# Replicate Hardware Back Button Functionality from UI in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to write a windows phone application and am wondering if it's possible to have a software button in the UI that does the same thing as the hardware back button (just sends a system back command).  I can't seem to find any information on how to do this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnBack" Content="Back" Click="btnBack_Click"></Button>
```

CS:

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    else
        App.Current.Terminate();
}
```

This would work as same **Back button.** if any **back-state** is there it would go to that state or if not it would **close (Terminate)** the Application.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you can override the back button function

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  //Do your work here
  base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  This works in most cases but I don't think I was able to use this in my scenario (it's been a long time, I don't remember exactly what I was trying to do, but I'm going back in my account and marking things correct/upvoting as appropriate